# Obter mensagem com erro no WebRequest C#

Tags: c#, http-request, webrequest

Estou realizando uma requisição via webrequest no c#, porém quando ocorre erro só consigo capturar o titulo padrão do erro. Caso eu faça a mesma requisição no insomnia ou postman, é retornado o corpo do erro disponibilizado pela api.

Exemplo: Enviei um produto para o webservice, porém o mesmo está faltando alguma informação nessa requisição, pelo insomnia é retornado no corpo um json contendo a informação :
*{"message": "O Campo Gtin é obrigatório"}* com erro 400.
Porém pelo C# só consigo capturar o erro 400 e a mensagem *"Bad request"*.

Quero saber de um jeito que eu possa capturar o corpo retornado.

Tratamento e captura do erro fiz da forma abaixo:

```
   {
        Requisicao.response_text = e.Message;
        Requisicao.status_text = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription;
        Requisicao.status_code = ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode obter a string de erro da seguinte forma:

```
string errorMessage = await e.Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Olá, este método que vc sugeriu é do componente HTTPClient, aqui usamos o componente WebRequest. Mesmo assim obrigado!

Comment: Encontrei a situação nesse link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261986/how-to-get-error-information-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-fails